# How did Angela cast the spell in Inheritance?

Tags: spells, inheritance-cycle

Anyone has any idea how Angela cast the spell beneath Dras Leona, that took out the group of soldiers? 
The one with time being movement and movement being warmth, while warmth and energy is but the same thing. 
I've thought alot about this, and can't come up with an answer

Comment: What she's saying is basically this: Time = Motion, Motion (on an atomic level) = Heat, Heat = Energy. It doesn't hold any water to a physicist, but for Paolini's audience and in a fantasy world, it's 'plausible'.

Comment: oddly enough, this question is 5 months older than the other, but that one has an answer, so I'm VTC this as the dupe.

Comment: The elements of her spell are all true scientifically, but not usually all at once. Making them true all at once would mean that in order to stay alive, you would have to move at a constant speed and never stop moving to remain and this is impossible.